# Can I pass in private variables to a UIViewController that will be instantiate via a Storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, arguments, init

I have a 'root' UIViewController, that itself instantiates two other UIViewControllers. However I need to pass something down into each of these, that has to be done at initialisation.

BUT

All 3 UIViewControllers are instantiated via the Storyboard.

Is this possible? Or should I look at some other design pattern to pass this data around?

Specifically, I'm trying to avoid close-coupling, however the 2 UIViewControllers that the 'root' one is instantiating, don't know about each other, but in both, there is a requirement that they know the value of a variable.

I **could** make this variable a static on the 'root' but that forces coupling.

I could make a global 'constants' swift file and put the variable in there, but that seems dirty and hacky.

Ideally, I'd like to pass this variable into each of these UIViewControllers at instantiation but as they are both loaded from the Storyboard I can't get this to work.

I've seen blogs and stack posts about similar things e.g.

https://blog.scottlogic.com/2014/11/20/swift-initialisation.html

but I've not seen a conclusive approach.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

The 'example' code below **obviously** doesn't work but it's there to show you what I'm trying to do, with of course the condition that all three of these UIViewControllers have an entry in Interface Builder and are instantiated with those from the Storyboard...

```
class root : UIViewController
{
    private let a: CGFloat = 1.0
    private let b: CGFloat = 10.0

    private let vc1: firstViewController
    private let vc2: secondViewController

    override init()
    {
        self.vc1 = firstViewController(a: a, b: b)
        self.vc2 = secondViewController(a: a, b: b)

        super.init
    }
}


class firstViewController : UIViewController
{
    private let a: CGFloat
    private let b: CGFloat

    init(a: CGFloat, b: CGFloat)
    {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        super.init(aDecoder: Decoder)
    }
}
```

This also comes down to how to 'chain' UIViewController instantiation...which I've yet to find a blog or tutorial or explanation on.

Thanks for any help / advice.

Comment: You can do that using storyBoards, so you create viewController from code or pass in prepareforSegue or before presenting, but since all var are private then, you can not

Comment: Unrelated to the question at hand, but as a matter of convention, class names should always start with upper case letters, e.g. `RootViewController` and `FirstViewController` instead of `root` and `firstViewController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical solution is to implement [`prepare(for:sender:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepare), which gives you a chance to set properties in the destination view controller. And if you want to keep them loosely coupled, you can use a protocol:

```
protocol DataDestination {
    var a: CGFloat? { get set }
    var b: CGFloat? { get set }
}

class RootViewController: UIViewController {
    private let a: CGFloat = 1.0
    private let b: CGFloat = 10.0

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? DataDestination {
            destination.a = a
            destination.b = b
        }
    }
}

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, DataDestination {
    var a: CGFloat?
    var b: CGFloat?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(a,b)           // by the time we hit this, those will be set
    }
}
```

Clearly, you’d give your protocol a more meaningful name, but we might want to know more about the app to make better suggestions.

Comment: Hi Rob. Thank you so much for taking the time to reply and write some pseudo-code.

I have a question; doe the variables in the 'FirstViewController' have to be Optionals? Can they be private let CGFloats and **not** optional? 

And considering that the 'RootViewController' instantiates these other two ViewControllers, even though they have their storyboard entries, there's no 'transition' from root to presenting either VC... so will 'prepareForSegue' actually get called?

Comment: No, they cannot be `private let`. First, if they’re getting set from external source, then `private` doesn’t make sense. By definition, you need to expose interface to set them. And because instantiating from storyboard, you can’t initialize them during `init`. So they either have to be optionals or you need to initialize them to some value, e.g. `0` during `init` and then let `RootViewController` update them to whatever later.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. I'll refactor to try this out. I've marked it as the answer in anticipation. 

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Re `prepareForSegue`, that obviously only works if doing segue (whether a presentation or an embed segue). So, the question is what you do after you manually instantiate these destination view controllers in code. But let’s say you can’t use segue easily (e.g. these are pages in `UIPageViewController`), then you can just set `a` and `b` after `storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Rob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57340259/8125224), you can assign Storyboard IDs to first and second view controllers by navigating to Interface Builder -> Identity Inspector. And then instantiate and setup them like:

```
let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
if let firstVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstVCIdentifier") as? FirstViewController {
    firstVC.a = self.a // ('a' must not be private in firstVC)
}
```

And to present them:

```
self.present(firstVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```